# What is the simplest way to get generic IEnumerable<T> from System.Collections.IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, collections

What is the simplest way to get generic `IEnumerable<T>` from `System.Collections.IEnumerable` (which contains only T type elements) ?

Something say to me that there should be simple (**avoiding LINQ**) standard wrapper, but I can't find it.

Comment: I don't understand your question, can you be more clear?

Comment: Use OfType or Cast extensions.

Comment: Most likely you are seeking the `Cast` method, but it's considered LINQ (defined in `Enumerable` class). If you are sure it contains only `T` type elements, you can use simple C# cast, e.g. `(IEnumerable<T>)enumerable`

Comment: @IvanStoev simple cast will only work if underlying type _also_ implements `IEnumerable<T>`. For example `static IEnumerable Test() { yield return 1;yield return 2;}` contains only elements of type `int` but cannot be casted to `IEnumerable<int>`.

Comment: @MarcoSalerno instead of "avoiding Linq" I want to say avoid "Linq.Expression". In my imagination every System.Linq functionality had Expression parsing inside :) what was overklill for such task, but now I see that it is false. Cast<T> doesn't contain Expression and is what I need.

Comment: @Evk Ok, ok, same for `ArrayList`, `HashTable` etc., of course `Cast` is the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest and shortest is with LINQ. You can enumerate it without LINQ:

```
foreach (T item in IEnumerableCollection)
```

and this is pretty much what [`.Cast<T>()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,152b93d25e224365) does:

```
static IEnumerable<TResult> CastIterator<TResult>(IEnumerable source) {
    foreach (object obj in source) yield return (TResult)obj;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. You are right Cast<T> even if it is from System.Linq namespace doesn't contain Expression what I really want to avoid.